# Listview with webviews: Avoid page load delay?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

Stakeholders in my project are bitten by cross platform/HTML bug. They want to have html pages dynamically created with js libraries (they are not even using phonegap or sencha) and display the view in native list. I am against this idea for obvious reason but am helpless.

I tried to reduce the delay in loading the html page to webview and I am successful to some extent. I am caching the dynamically created html page and loading it to webview when list view is scrolled etc. I also  avoid reloading the page which is already loaded in webview. These approach improved delay but still there is delay.

I was wondering is it possible to access the webview and preload prior to getView() method of the list view adapter is called ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListView` row contains `WebView` then there is not possible to load WebView before `getView()` gets called, because each row of ListView is created in `getView()` method only. So, it won't be possible to access the view(`WebView` in your case) before it is loaded or added to the `ListView`.